# using io.Pipes() for sending and receiving message

Tags: go

I am using os.Pipes() in my program, but for some reason it gives a bad file descriptor error each time i try to write or read data from it.

Is there some thing I am doing wrong?

Below is the code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {

    writer, reader, err := os.Pipe()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }


    _,err= writer.Write([]byte("hello"))


    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    var data []byte

    _, err = reader.Read(data)


    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(data))
}
```

output :
write |0: Invalid argument
read |1: Invalid argument

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using an [`os.Pipe`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Pipe), which returns  a pair of FIFO connected files from the os. This is different than an [`io.Pipe`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Pipe) which is implemented in Go.

The `invalid argument` errors are because you are reading and writing to the wrong files. The signature of `os.Pipe` is

```
func Pipe() (r *File, w *File, err error)
```

which shows that the returns values are in the order "reader, writer, error".

and `io.Pipe`:

```
func Pipe() (*PipeReader, *PipeWriter)
```

Also returning in the order "reader, writer"

When you check the error from the `os.Pipe` function, you are only printing the value. If there was an error, the files are invalid. You need to return or exit on that error.

Pipes are also blocking (though an os.Pipe has a small, hard coded buffer), so you need to read and write asynchronously. If you swapped this for an `io.Pipe` it would deadlock immediately. Dispatch the Read method inside a goroutine and wait for it to complete.

Finally, you are reading into a `nil` slice, which will read nothing. You need to allocate space to read into, and you need to record the number of bytes read to know how much of the buffer is used.

A more correct version of your example would look like:

```
reader, writer, err := os.Pipe()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

var wg sync.WaitGroup
wg.Add(1)
go func() {
    defer wg.Done()
    data := make([]byte, 1024)

    n, err = reader.Read(data)
    if n > 0 {
        fmt.Println(string(data[:n]))
    }

    if err != nil && err != io.EOF {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}()

_, err = writer.Write([]byte("hello"))
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}

wg.Wait()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Did not check the order of return values, wasted a lot of time.